# How to loop and send values in array to multiple textboxes in selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I am trying to loop array and send each value to different TextBoxes or inputs with Selenium using Python.

```
textBoxes = bot.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')
 for title in titles:
     for box in textBoxes:
         box.send_keys(title)
```

It is a small window with textboxes inside it. I already looped these texboxes and it is sending the whole array inside of each textbox. But I need to send first value in array into the first textbox, second value in array into the second textbox and so on..

Is it possible to handle this situation with looping? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `range` to loop:

```
textBoxes = bot.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')
for i in range(len(titles)):
    textBoxes[i].send_keys(titles[i])
```